# How to configure logitech C525 on raspberrypi

Tags: raspbian, camera

I wan to use Logitech C525 on raspberrypi because of its autofocus features but I cannot find any resources if it is compatible with raspi  could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

According to the elinux list of verified [webcams](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Webcams) the Logitech C525 should work without problem. A comparison of several webcams including the Pi cam and the Logitech C525 can be found [here](https://www.intorobotics.com/raspberry-pi-camera-guide/).

Comment: I can confirm that the Logitech C525 does *NOT* work. More precisely: Gives a low-resolution black-and-white picture only. No matter what the palette (6,8,17) or the resolution (640x480, 1280x720) settings for Motion are. HW: Raspberry Pi 2B. OS: Raspbian 11 "Bullseye".  Motion V4.3.2. The camera works perfectly when plugged into a Mac.